# Exception while updating date & time on background for Android OS ver 2.2 & above

Tags: android

I am using one class & interface for calculating/updating date & time.

**The interface:**

```
public interface CListener {

    public void updateClock(String date, String time);

}
```

**The class:**

```
public class CManager {

    private CListener mListener = null;

    private static Timer mTimer = null;

    private static String mDateData = "";

    private static String mTimeData = "";

    private static  CManager _instance = null;

    private CManager() {

        if (mTimer == null) {

            mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    updateTime();
                }

            }, 0, 1000);
        }
    }


    public static CManager getInstance() {
          if(_instance == null ) {
             _instance = new CManager ();
          }
          return _instance;
       }


    public void setClockListener(ClockListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }


    public void updateTime() {


            Date d = new Date();

                        // Calculating the date , month ,day ,hr ,min from Date d

            mListener.updateClock(mDateData, mTimeData);

            // mDateData -> Calculated combined Date
            // mTimeData -> Calculated combined time


    }


    public String getDate() {
        return mDateData;
    }


    public String getTime() {
        return mTimeData;
    }
}
```

**I am calling the CManager class from an activity**

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity{


private CManager mCManager = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

mCManager = CManager.getInstance();

 }
```

The above code is working perfectly & updating date & time with Android OS version 1.6 to 2.1 .

But the same code is giving the following error for Android OS version 2.2. & above.

```
04-08 03:57:39.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(419): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
04-08 03:57:39.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(419): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 03:57:39.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(419): at com.app.CManager.updateTime(CManager.java:144)
04-08 03:57:39.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(419):     at com.app.CManager$1.run(CManager.java:54)
04-08 03:57:39.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(419):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
04-08 03:57:39.301: WARN/ActivityManager(70):   Force finishing activity com.app/.SampleActivity
```

What can be the possible reason for the problem ?
Is there any alternative/work around for this issue.

Kindly provide your inputs/sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 0):

Have you set mListener?

You should check (mListener != null) in any event, as the background thread is created in your constructor, which means in can try to execute between CManager.getInstance and a call to setClockListener()

As you're using a singleton, it might be better to support multiple CListeners instead of one.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello